# Server error in tfs

Tags: tfs

I couldn't access TFS 2010 using the following URL. I am getting the following error message.

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to validate data.]

test:8080/tfs/
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Does TFS stands for Microsoft Team Foundation Server ?

Comment: yes. It is Team Foundation server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On App Tier server, goto C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Access\Web.
   (Please make a copy of Web.config, just in case you need the original file later.)
2. Edit the Web.config file in notepad.
3. Search "machineKey" in Web.config file.
4. Replace the  section with text below.

   ```
   <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/>
   ```
5. Save the Web.config file.
6. Restart the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) service.

[Source](http://nvn-sharma.blogspot.com/2012/10/tfs-webaccess-error-httpexception.html)